# I want to convert array values to single object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have tried following code and I get an array but I want to create the following output:

```
var hid_col_arr = [];
if (hiddenFieldsArr.length) {
  $.each(hiddenFieldsArr, function (hid_field, hid_field_label) {
    hid_col_arr[hid_field] = {targets: hid_field_label.original, orderData: hid_field_label.hidden, visible: false};
  });
  console.log(hid_col_arr);
}
```

output:

```
[
  0: {
    targets: 4, 
    orderData: 4, 
    visible: false
  }, 
  1: {
    targets: 5, 
    orderData: 5, 
    visible: false
  }
]
```

I want output:

```
{
  targets: 4, 
  orderData: 4, 
  visible: false
}, {
  targets: 5, 
  orderData: 5, 
  visible: false
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is a valid format, unless you are literally trying to print the objects on one single string

Comment: Your desired output is incorrect. Arrays are indexed with numbers . and objects are indexed with string key. Your desired output is neither an array or an object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to get an array from an object:

```js
const output = {
  0: {
    targets: 4,
    orderData: 4,
    visible: false
  },
  1: {
    targets: 5,
    orderData: 5,
    visible: false
  }
};

const arr = Object.values(output).sort((a, b) => a.orderData - b.orderData);
console.log(arr);
```

<sub>(The sorting is relevant to keep the objects in order)</sub>